# Какое средство выразительности использовано в предложении?

Tags: тропы

Он вздохнул, вновь отключил телефон, положил его в карман и, чтобы отвлечься от дурных мыслей, стал методично складывать цифры в номерах проезжавших мимо машин.

Мне кажется, что в этом предложении есть метафора. Я не права?

Comment: А где именно метафора?

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу слов в переносном значении - скрытых сравнений, вижу только речевой недочёт: сотовый телефон всё-таки не отключают, а **выключают**, отключают стационарный (домашний) телефон, например за неуплату, а  выключают из сети.

Все действия в прямом значении. Вы имели в виду сочетание **складывать цифры**? Но складывать - математическое действие сложения, это прямое значение. Вот если бы он  куда-то в угол складывал таблички с цифрами, а сказал "складывал цифры", была бы метафора - метонимия. Единственное средство выразительности здесь синтаксическое - ряд однородных членов.

Answer (score 0):

Никакого. Цифры, они и есть цифры, где бы человек их не размещал. К тому же фраза (уж не знаю её источник, не стал уточнять) кривая. Русский человек говорит: "цифры на номерах", как бы подразумевая, что они нанесены на эту белую продолговатую панельку, а не замурованы в неё. А автор написал так, будто цифры реально где-то внутри. Ещё можно понять, когда номер очень длинный, и в нём есть несколько цифр, которые использовали. Но здесь речь явно не о том, и номер, наверняка, стандартный, включающий три-четыре цифры.
Допустимо сказать двумя образами:

> Цифры на номерах
>
> Цифры из номеров

Это, конечно, не по вопросу. Но по вопросу нечего добавить. Можете просто загуглить приёмы образной речи и попытаться подставить их к своему случаю. Ничего не выйдет. И да: не надо писать названия меток, разбивая их на отдельные слова. То, о чём Вы спросили, называется одним словом: "тропы". Если нужно написать несколько слов, можно сделать это в одной метке. А вообще, когда есть сомнения, всегда лучше воспользоваться меткой "общие".

Answer (score 0):

Можно предположить переносное значение слова ***методично***. Тогда это действительно метафора.

**Прямое значение** наречия:  планомерно, старательно, вдумчиво, целенаправленно,  кропотливо, скрупулёзно,  последовательно, сосредоточенно.

Но в данном случае ***методично*** – это неосознанно, машинально, безотчетно.

Таким образом автор изображает душевное состояние героя.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**Попробую еще раз объяснить, что такое метафора.**

Метафора (от греч. metaphora – перенос) – вид тропа, предполагающий перенос наименования с одной реалии на другую на основе сходства признаков.

Персонаж складывает цифры  машинально, бездумно, безотчетно, чтобы чем-то занять свой разум. Здесь **нецеленаправленное, машинальное действие приравнивается к действию целенаправленному и осознанному по размеренности и сосредоточенности**,   с которыми оно выполняется.

Поэтому значение у наречия *методично* в данном тексте **переносное.**

Comment: Вообще-то, методично - это  строго размеренно, обдуманно, аккуратно...Значение само по себе переносное, но методично складывать цифры - употреблено не как метафора, а в прямом значении "размеренно". А что  с чем здесь скрыто сравнивается? Размеренно-аккуратно производить действие сложения. Не вижу метафоры.